# Getting points given center and radius (working with latitude and longitude)

Tags: calculus, geodesy

I'm trying to solve a problem and I'm sure it is quite easy but I'm not a mathematician at all:

Here it goes:

I'm trying to draw the coverage area of a satellite, which is supposed to be circular.

To calculate this, I have the center of the coverage area (which is the current satellite position) in coordinates [lat, lon] and the radius of the coverage area in meters (let's say something like 4000-5000 meters).

I need to get all the points [lat,lon] that describe the coverage area, in order to draw it. That is, I need the points that describe the circle's perimeter. The problem here is that meters and coordinates are combined.

Any idea of the formula needed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $x$ is longitude, $y$ is latitude and $x_c$, $y_c$ is the current position, thise formula will give you what you want: $(x-x_c)^2+(y-y_c)^2=5000^2$

Comment: Supposing 5000 as radius, right?

Comment: Yes, it's the radius. you just need to be aware that this equation may lead to negative $x$ and $y$ and you need to translate those into correct coordinates (negative $x$ means west of the prime meridian, negative $y$ means it's below equator)